# Is it possible to move the first few letters in a string to the end of a cell in Excel?

Tags: macos, ms-office

So if I have a number of cells with something like this in them:

```
women/colour/type
```

Is it possible to ask excel to move the women part to the end of the cell? e.g.

```
colour/type/women
```

I could really do with some help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even better can you put the data into separate cells so women colour and type are in separate columns

Comment: Actually no not at the moment it is for some work I am doing SEO wise and it is for categorisation of products. Unfortunately

Comment: Not really the question you're asking here, but Mark has the right idea. If you separate your data out into different columns, you'll need to adjust your analysis to accommodate (in the short term), but should later find that it will provide a much more flexible way to access the data.

Comment: At a minimum - you'll find it much easier to put your data together in any order you like if you split it up, using the concatenate function in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit of a hack but try the following assuming the field you want to evaluate is at `A1`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)+1,LEN(RIGHT(A1, FIND("/",A1,1)))-1)&"/"& RIGHT(A1, FIND("/",A1,1)-2)&"/"& LEFT(A1, FIND("/",A1,1)-1)
```

This is broken down into three parts (split by the `&"/"&`):

- Left: `=LEFT(A1, FIND("/",A1,1)-1)` returns `woman`
- Middle:`=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)+1,LEN(RIGHT(A1, FIND("/",A1,1)))-1)`returns
  `colour`
- Right: `=RIGHT(A1, FIND("/",A1,1)-2)` returns `type`

Put the parts into the new order add the `&"/"&` dividers back in and voila.